# serve hot reload on the network

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have computer with debian what share me folder via nettalk. On this debian I run test server `npm run serve`
next 192.168.0.x:8080 and it works.

The problem is with checking in background
`sockjs.js?9be2:1605 GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1554826524135 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` it try call to localhost. How to force on it my network address?

Second issues is that I use scss and compile it to css by default sass tool. It means that outside of vue. it's not styled components.

When I run npm serve on the local machine to load new css file I need to reload page in browser.
When it works on the machine in my local network I need to re-boot npm run serve and reload page in browser.

Thanks for any hints where I can configure such things.
I expect that I should push `process.env.BASE_URL` but I've been tried create `.env.local` and push there `BASE_URL`. In the all `BASE_URL` still is "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone need to solve similar problem, I found solution.

in the `/vue.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
    public: '192.168.0.x:8080'
  }
}
```

will solve issue with the call to localhost by socket listener.

Reload styles I solved different way.
I use scss as pre-processor and I used `node-sass`, `sass-loader` modules
and in the App.vue

```
<template>...</template>
<script>...</script>
<style lang="scss">
  @import "path/to/your.scss";
</style>
```

it is working with hot reload in scss files.